# How do I filter through an NSArray of NSDate objects to find next closest date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to figure out how to filter through an `NSArray` of `NSDate` objects to find the next closest one (like a bus stop app). The day does not matter whatsoever. All that matters in the `NSDate` object is the hour and minute since it is the same for every day.

I am trying to do this for iOS and from my research it seems that there is no `dateWithString` method for iOS (ignore my code for the most part, it is just there to outline what I am trying to accomplish). I have looked through a lot of stuff like `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` and can't seem to figure it out. I just want to be able to filter through a `NSArray` of `NSDate` objects to find the next coming bus (next closest `NSDate` object). Please help me adjust my code.

```
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"06:40:00"]; // 6:40 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T2 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"07:50:00"]; // 7:50 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T3 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"08:20:00"]; // 8:20 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T4 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"08:50:00"]; // 8:50 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T5 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"09:20:00"]; // 9:20 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T6 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"09:50:00"]; // 9:50 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T7 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"10:20:00"]; // 10:20 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T8 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"10:50:00"]; // 10:50 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T9 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"11:20:00"]; // 11:20 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T10 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"11:50:00"]; // 11:50 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T11 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"12:20:00"]; // 12:20 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T12 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"12:50:00"]; // 12:50 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T13 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"13:20:00"]; // 1:20 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T14 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"13:50:00"]; // 1:50 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T15 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"14:20:00"]; // 2:20 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T16 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"14:50:00"]; // 2:50 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T17 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"15:20:00"]; // 3:20 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T18 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"15:50:00"]; // 3:50 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T19 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"16:20:00"]; // 4:20 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T20 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"16:50:00"]; // 4:50 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T21 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"17:20:00"]; // 5:20 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T22 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"17:50:00"]; // 5:50 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T23 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"18:20:00"]; // 6:20 PM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T24 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"19:05:00"]; // 7:05 PM

NSArray *bus500Times = @[bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T2,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T3,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T4,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T5,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T6,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T7,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T8,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T9,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T10,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T11,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T12,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T13,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T14,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T15,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T16,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T17,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T18,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T19,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T20,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T21,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T22,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T23,
                         bus500_monday_To_Friday_T24];

NSDate *currentTime;
NSDate *closestTime500;

while(YES)
{
    currentTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]
                                     sinceDate:[NSDate date]];

    int i = 0;
    for(NSDate *date in bus500Times)
    {
        if([date timeIntervalSinceDate:currentTime] > 0)
        {
            closestTime500 = date;
            break;
        }
    }

    double negativeSecondsUntilNextBusDepart500 = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:closestTime500];

    // Have to get the magnitude (positive) of the negative secodns value
    double realSecondsUntilNextBusDepart500 = negativeSecondsUntilNextBusDepart500+((-negativeSecondsUntilNextBusDepart500)*2);

    // Casting seconds to an integer so modulus can happen in following code
    int seconds500 = (int)realSecondsUntilNextBusDepart500;

    // Formatting the seconds into days, hours, minutes, seconds
    int hours500 = seconds500/3600;
    seconds500 = seconds500%3600;
    int minutes500 = seconds500/60;
    seconds500 = seconds500%60;

    // Displaying information to the screen
    if(hours500 > 0)
        NSLog(@"%d HOURS, %d MINUTES, %d SECONDS", hours500, minutes500, seconds500);

    else if(minutes500 > 0)
        NSLog(@"%d MINUTES, %d SECONDS", minutes500, seconds500);

    else
        NSLog(@"%d SECONDS", seconds500);

    NSLog(@"\n");
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparison between two times in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034452/comparison-between-two-times-in-objective-c)

Comment: I don't know what `dateWithString`, but you can use a `NSPredicate` to filter the array getting all the date AFTER the chosen date (and guessing that's your NSArray is ordered), and pick the first object of the new array.

Comment: There is no `dateWithString`, instead you need to use `NSDateFormatter`, set the `dateFormat` to whatever your format is, and use `[formatter dateFromString:dateString]`

Comment: Why do you even want to convert to an NSDate?  You have your times in character form, and if you're careful to never omit "insignificant" zeros, etc, they will sort and compare just fine.  If you convert to NSDate that just adds complications.

Comment: I do not see any other way to do it other than having them as NSDates. I am thinking that comparing how many seconds away from the start of a day will work, but I am not sure how to do that in code :S

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an array of certain times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501899/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-certain-times)

Comment: You asked a nearly [**identical question yesterday**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501899/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-certain-times), to which I provided a comprehensive answer. As @HotLicks points out, you could also form your times into strings (being careful to use 24 hour time and leading zeros in all cases) and then compare the strings, and get correct results. Figuring out the amount of time between now and a saved time would be a little more complicated in that case however.

Comment: "I am thinking that comparing how many seconds away from the start of a day will work, but I am not sure how to do that in code."  You don't know how to do arithmetic?  The time is `hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds`.

Comment: Hi sorry. I do not understand what you mean. Yes I know basic arithmetic but I don't see what I can do to store times in anything but an NSDate. I do not understand what you mean by this: "You have your times in character form, and if you're careful to never omit "insignificant" zeros, etc, they will sort and compare just fine" I do not know how to compare the time difference if it is in characters. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDate`'s `-timeIntervalSinceDate:` (or `-timeIntervalSinceNow`) method to find the difference between a given date (or the current date). Do this for each date in your array until you find the one with the smallest difference (and the correct sign). Simply iterating over the array would work fine, but another way is to use `NSArray`'s [`-indexOfObjectPassingTest:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW21) method.

Comment: Except that he wants to "sort" by time, ignoring date.  (And he doesn't know how to use NSDateFormatter to convert a string to an NSDate.)

Comment: There was no mention of sort, only finding the next time.

Comment: `NSDate` probably isn't the right tool in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `dateWithString` that you acknowledge doesn't work, you need to use `NSDateFormatter` to convert a string to a date.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"H:mm:ss";
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"06:40:00"]; // 6:40 AM
NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"07:50:00"]; // 7:50 AM
...etc
```

You can then compare the current date to your bus time `NSDate` values (or whatever your reference date is) using `NSDate`'s `timeIntervalSinceDate:`